# CRC-16/Modbus Implementation in C# malfunction

Tags: c#, serial-port, crc, modbus, crc16

I'm currently setting up the communication between a controller for a step motor and a computer, coding an application in C# (it is the first time I use this programming language, and although I'm not a computer scientist but an industrial engineer, reason why I'm sure there are some ways of optimizing the function which I don't know, any recommendation on that matter would also be very appreciated). Therefore, I've been using the RS-485 that the controller has to communicate with it, and I've implemented an algorithm that generates the CRC(Cyclic Redundancy Check) bytes required.

And there is where my problem begins. I can't find the reason why my function doesn't generate the correct CRC value. I have checked with some online calculators of CRC and I've also used the example that appears in the [Modbus Guide](https://modbus.org/docs/Modbus_over_serial_line_V1.pdf) (where it also explains how is the code implemented).

Here is the code I've written for the calculus of the CRC:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // 0x05, 0x06, 0x17, 0x70, 0x00, 0x01 
            byte[] prueba = new byte[] { 0x02, 0x07 };
            byte[] result = Aux.CRC(prueba);
            Console.WriteLine(result[0] + " " + result[1]);
        }
    }

class Aux{
public static byte[] CRC(byte[] to_evaluate)
        {
            byte[] CRC_Byte = new byte[2] { 0, 0 };
            UInt16 CRC_Register = 0xFFFF;            //16 bits 1111.1111.1111.1111
            UInt16 CRC_pol = 0xa001;                 //16 bits 1010.0000.0000.0001

            foreach (UInt16 byte_val in to_evaluate)
            {
                CRC_Register ^= byte_val;
                Console.WriteLine("XOR inicial : {0:X}", CRC_Register);

                for (byte i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    CRC_Register >>= 1;
                    Console.WriteLine("Desplazamiento " + (i + 1) + ": {0:X}", CRC_Register);

                    if ((CRC_Register & 1) != 0)
                    {
                        CRC_Register ^= CRC_pol;
                        Console.WriteLine("XOR: {0:X}", CRC_Register);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0:X}",CRC_Register);

            byte low_byte_CRC = (byte)((CRC_Register << 8) >> 8);
            byte high_byte_CRC = (byte)(CRC_Register >> 8);

            CRC_Byte[0] = low_byte_CRC;
            CRC_Byte[1] = high_byte_CRC;

            return CRC_Byte;
        }
}
```

The expected result using the test array attached and the polinomial 0xa001 is 0x1241 for CRC_Register, and {0x41,0x12} for the CRC_Byte.

Comment: I believe the bit you should be checking for in this part: `if ((CRC_Register & 1) != 0)` is the one that you just shifted out two lines above.

Comment: It may be, but in order to calculate the CRC, if I'm not wrong, the procedure is: 1.- CRC_Register XOR byte_val. 2.- CRC_Register  >> 1. 3.- Check if the LSB is 1 or 0, and in case it is 0 -> CRC_Register >> 1. Until you've shifted a total of 8 times.

Comment: Could you include a test input `byte array` as well as the expected CRC value?

Comment: Yes, just done! The input array I've used is 0x0207. It is the test byte array of the Modbus link. The expected CRC_Register value is 0x1241, and the CRC_Byte = {0x42, 0x12}, but using a different polinomial (0xa001).

Comment: I haven't checked your logic yet - but the documentation you linked to says the polynomial value should be 0xA001 not 0x8005 - you seem to have the bit order reversed

Comment: True, I've used that one before. I've changed the polinomial because I've started using an online calculator to check which used other polinomial.

Comment: See this : https://ctlsys.com/support/how_to_compute_the_modbus_rtu_message_crc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to implement a CRC check for PPP once in C# and it was absolutely no fun!

I found in [this link](https://ctlsys.com/support/how_to_compute_the_modbus_rtu_message_crc/) the code that should correctly generate the CRC.  It follows the CRC Generation procedure from section 6.2.2 on page 39 of the document you shared the link to.

```
// Compute the MODBUS RTU CRC
UInt16 ModRTU_CRC(byte[] buf, int len)
{
    UInt16 crc = 0xFFFF;
  
    for (int pos = 0; pos < len; pos++) 
    {
        crc ^= (UInt16)buf[pos];          // XOR byte into least sig. byte of crc
  
        for (int i = 8; i != 0; i--)      // Loop over each bit
        {    
            if ((crc & 0x0001) != 0)        // If the LSB is set
            {      
                crc >>= 1;                    // Shift right and XOR 0xA001
                crc ^= 0xA001;
            }
            else                            // Else LSB is not set
            {                            
                crc >>= 1;                    // Just shift right
            }
        }
    }
    // Note, this number has low and high bytes swapped, so use it accordingly (or swap bytes)
    return crc;  
}
```

Comment: I've implemented the if..else that appears on the code you attached (although I can't see where is exactly the difference whit mine). It works, so I just can say thank you hahaha

Comment: The difference is where & when you do the shift right. The LSB check is done first, if set the XOR is done after shift, otherwise it is shifted. Yours performs the shift first & then checks LSB.

Comment: Okay, but in both of the if statements the first thing you do is shift.

Comment: Okay, just seen it. It is necessary to check which is the value of the LSB before you choose  what are the operations your are gonna do. Thank you!!!